# Install4j - How can I install the MSVC++ Redistributable Binary if needed?

Tags: install4j

I'm wondering if there's some way to use my install4j utility to handle installing the MSVC++ redistributable libraries if they are not already on the client machine?

Is there anyone who has an example of how they did that to save me from re-inventing the wheel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "Run executable or batch file" action to run an external installer.

Most installers have an "unattended" mode that does not require user interaction. Activating unattended mode for the MSVC++ redistributable package varies from version to version, for 2010/2012 and 2013 the required arguments are

```
/passive /norestart
```

For 2015, the arguments are

```
/install /passive /norestart
```

In the editor of the "Arguments" property, make sure to put each argument on a new line.

Comment: Awesome. good stuff. so i can run that and it won't install it if it doesn't need it.

Comment: It worked, but it only worked when I launched a .cmd file with the command to run the installer. It did not work when i just launched the file by itself using the Run executable option. Install4j seemed to ignore my parameters.

Comment: Is each parameter on a separate line in the "Arguments" property? Please redirect the stdout and stderr output to the installation log so you can see the output of the external installer.