# How can I install the MSVC++ Redistributable 2008 in silent mode using Install4j?

Tags: install4j

I tried with "Run executable or batch file" action

```
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.RunExecutableAction [ID 36]: Execute action
       Property arguments: [/q]
       Property rollbackSupported: false
       Property includeParentEnvironmentVariables: true
       Property workingDirectory: .
       Property useRollbackExecutable: false
       Property rollbackExecutable: null
       Property rollbackWorkingDirectory: null
       Property rollbackArguments: null
       Property returnCodeVariable: 
       Property stdoutRedirectionMode: To log file
       Property stdoutVariableName: 
       Property failOnStdoutFileError: false
       Property stderrRedirectionMode: To log file
       Property stderrVariableName: 
       Property failOnStderrFileError: false
       Property stdinRedirectionMode: No redirection
       Property failOnStdinFileError: false
       Property environmentVariables: {}
       Property showWindowsConsole: false
       Property keepConsoleWindow: false
       Property executable: vcredist_x64_2008.exe
       Property wait: true
       Property waitForStreams: true
       Property timeout: 0
       Property logArguments: true
       Property stdoutFile: null
       Property stderrFile: null
       Property stdinString: 
       Property stdinFile: null
       used working dir: C:\Program Files\test\.
       execute using batch file
```

I am getting MSVC++ Redistributable popup window while installation of my application.

Please suggest the fix to avoid popup.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41356051/install4j-how-can-i-install-the-msvc-redistributable-binary-if-needed

Comment: I followed the same, It's working fine for VC++ Redistributable 2013 with vcredist_x64.exe /quiet . But not working for 2008 with vcredist_x64.exe /q

Comment: Likely it requires different command line arguments than the newer versions.

Comment: VC++ Redistributable 2008 silent installation working with custom script action by 'vcredist_x64.exe /q'